# "app isn't available" Facebook App Login Error

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-login

I'm seeking assistance with Facebook Login. When attempting to log in and obtain an access_token for utilization with the Facebook API, I encounter the error message "It appears that this app isn't available."

Unfortunately, I haven't been able to pinpoint a definitive explanation for this error. The permissions I've requested from Facebook include: pages_read_engagement, pages_show_list.

In an effort to resolve this issue, I've explored various suggestions, including those found on Stack Overflow:

1. Verified that the "App ID" and "App Secret" are accurate (as functionality is seamless from a developer account).
2. Confirmed that the app is in "Live" mode.
3. Adjusted email and public_profile permissions to advanced access.
4. Ensured correct configuration of "App Domain" and "OAuth Redirect URIs."
5. Added "Privacy Policy URL" and "Terms of Service URL" as required.

Despite these measures, the problem persists, and I am still in search of a clear solution. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

[Error Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xykc0.jpg)

Comment: Your request for advanced persmissions acess was approved?